# How to create two different Intent with the same Action?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Which fields in Intent (except Action) are unique to PendingIntent?
I want to create multiple instances of Intent with the same Action="MyName".
It is necessary that for AlarmManager were different instances.

```
//Instance 1
Intent intent1=new Intent("MyName");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time1.getTime(), pi);

//Instance 2
Intent intent2=new Intent("MyName");
....
TO-DO Add the difference of the intent2 from the intent1

pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time2.getTime(), pi);
```

In the future AlarmManager.cancel(PendingIntent)

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do here. Can you explain your goal please.

Comment: I want to create 2 different timers.
But thus in order for the Receiver I was able to configure IntentFilter
And so I could cancel each timer using AlarmManager.cancel

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#filterEquals(android.content.Intent)) for the Intent class it will consider two intents as equal according to these rules:

> That is, if their action, data, type, class, and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data included in the intents.

Set a different data parameter for your intents and it shouldn't resolve to the same `PendingIntent`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.package.action");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("scheme://somethingA"));

Intent otherIntent = new Intent("com.package.action");
otherIntent.setData(Uri.parse("scheme://somethingB"));
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad, but give `setData(Uri)` a shot, that should do the trick according to the documentation on `Intent.filterEquals`. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter in `getBroadcast()` is a `requestCode`, you can change it and the system will treat it as a different pending intent if the request codes are different.

Comment: I need the difference is in Intent.
Because I want to use IntentFilter to filter messages

Comment: Are you looking for Intent.putExtra()?

Comment: putExtra does not help.

Comment: I think you need to use `putExtra()` as well as putting the same id in the `requestCode`

Comment: PutExtra does not help. I just checked! First timer will be replaced by the second! Intent intent = new Intent (UUIDkey); intent.putExtra ("id", "1"); PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time.getTime(), pi); Intent intent2 = new Intent (UUIDkey); intent2.putExtra ("id", "2"); pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast (context, 0, intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Time.getTime(), pi2);

Comment: As I said, you need to change the requestCode as well: getBroadcast(Context context, **int requestCode**, Intent intent, int flags)

Comment: Also, you can use `putExtra("id", 1)` and `getIntExtra()`.

Comment: My goal is to make different Intent and intent2.
Unfortunately requestCode suitable, but not in my case.

Comment: putExtra("id", 1) - for example only
In real code I use UUID for full uniqueness

Comment: The extra makes the Intents different, the requestId makes it so the alarms can be set and cancelled separately. I fail to see your problem.